# Wildcards in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

I can't get the answers webpage for Microsoft to work so I have to come here.

I'm trying to to find and replace using wildcards so I want to replace anything which begins with yy( and then there will be some wildcards followed by a closed parentheses.  I want to replace that final closed parenthesis with )zz.  I wrote

yy(*)  to be replaced with yy(*)zz and selected use wildcards but that didn't work.

Comment: When I do that, I get `yy(*)zz( some characters )`.

Comment: If you feel a question belongs on Microsoft Answers, then the SuperUser site of Stack Exchange is the correct place to ask. StackOverflow is for programming questions. Questions concerning fields and wildcard searches are borderline, however, and can also be asked on StackOverflow. Just FYI :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following wildcard combinations (be sure to activate the `Use Wildcards` checkbox):

**Find** term: `(yy\(*\))`

**Replace** term: `\1zz`

**Explanation**:

1. Since Wildcard searches use special character combinations you must
   use `\(` and `\)` to specify opening/closing parentheses.
2. The parentheses at the beginning and end of a part of the `Find`
   term group that part as an "expression", so that it can be used in
   the`Replace` term.
3. The `\1` part of the `Replace` term refers to the first expression of the `Find` term. That means whatever was found that matches that expression will be added into the Replacement text (in this case, to the `zz`).

Additional Note: You can find special symbols for "Find" in the advanced Find dialog box by 1) clicking the "More" button, then 2) looking in the "Special" list.

Comment: I still can't get it to work.  I input in the find box `(yy\(*\)` and put in the replace box \1zz and the test was yy(hghgh) and it said 0 replacements were made. Also I selected 'use wildcards'.

Comment: If you click only on FindNext does it at least find the search term? I did test before I posted and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

In world 2010:

Body: yy(the system α in ; dlove zee )

find: `(yy\(*\))`

replace: `\1zz`

gives: yy(the system α in ; dlove zee )zz

works just fine. Please check if any newline character in between.